# Help trying to execute a sh on background

Tags: bash, ssh, putty, sh, background-process

Hi i have a problem trying to execute a sh script on background

```
/home/user/server-data/run.sh +exec server.cfg
```

i want execute that script on background but it dosen't work even if i use the & on the end of the line

Can someone help?

Comment: Is script even executable? You can see this with `ls -l` command and improve your answer

Comment: What is the error you're getting? How do you know it's failing?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
nohup script.sh &
```

to execute a script and be able to close the terminal.
To fully detach, you can also run a command like:

```
script.sh </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

In your case, you may also want to see if the server you are using has a "daemon" mode that you could pass as an argument to the server command.

There are other options that you may want to check out like  "screen" and "tmux" that run a separate terminal so you can detach and resume later.